# C++ how to select multiple objects using lambda find_if

Tags: c++, object, vector, lambda, iterator

I am trying to go through a vector of objects and then select the one matching specific ID. The example below would print first object that matches the ID but how do I print or select few objects that are matching the same ID? I tried using while loop and it would work however because I have to increase iterator every time, I would always get the "Segmentation fault".

```
it = find_if(database.begin(), database.end(), [&id](cd &c) {
    return c.getId() == id;
});

int index = std::distance(database.begin(), it); //finding index of the object
database[index].print(); //prints everything from the object
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop.

Comment: @Ron I tried however inline function is not going to work inside for loop

Comment: please show the code that does not work. Afaik there is no algorithm that does exactly what you need. You could use `for_each`, but thats also just a for loop in disguise

Comment: @Ron you answered my question, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As-is that would require some kind of loop. There is no one-liner for what you want to do. I think you want to use the [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) function instead.

Answer (score 3):

There are several alternatives including:

```
for (auto& c: database) {
    if (c.getId() == id) {
        c.print();
    }
}
```

or

```
  auto next_it = [&](auto beg) {
      return std::find_if(beg, database.end(),
          [&id](cd &c) {
              return c.getId() == id;
          });
  };

  for (auto it = next_it(database.begin()); it != database.end(); it = next_it(it + 1)) {
      it->print();
  }
```

or (with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3))

```
for (auto& c: database | ranges::filter([&](const auto& c){ return c.getId() == id; })) {
    c.print();
}
```